# is there any feature of aliasing fields and setting defaults value for a field in mongo db while fetching results without aggregations?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

1) select f1 as field_one from table; 
so f1 is aliased to field_one.

2) select decode(f1, 1,one, 2, two, 3, three, 'Not a valid range' ) from table.
so for value of f1 query returns 
1 One
2 Two
3 Three
else 
Not a valid range

Answer (score 0):

@Ankita, In Aggregation framework you have following two to address the requested features:

1. Aliasing: You can use `$project` to assign a new name - http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/

   db.coll.aggregate([{"$project": {"field_one": "$f1"}])
2. Decode: You should be able to use combination of `$concat` and `$cond` to the put a decode kind of statement. You can find more details bout the cond and concat in the MongoDB documentation at http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/ and http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/concat/

   db.coll.aggregate([{$project: {decode_fields: {"$concat": [{"$cond": [, , ] }, {....}] } } }])

Comment: Thanks @aks. Actually I was looking for it without aggs. Also I do not wanna write multiple conditions for decode.

Comment: There are no options for similar functionality in the regular find() commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing a query to insert the results into another collection or database, you can manipulate the way each line looks line inside the `forEach` function. Take a look:

```
db.getCollection('yourCollection').find({
    property: {
        $in: [ 71038, 41438 ]
    }}
).forEach(function(line) {
    line.id = NumberInt(line.id);
    line.alteredProperty = line.property;
    delete line.property;
    line.updatedAt = line.meta.updatedAt;
    line.createdAt = line.meta.createdAt;
    delete line.meta;
    db.otherCollections.insert(line);
})
```

Is this of any help? :)